# undefined reference to QCamera constructor

Tags: pi-2, camera, cross-compilation, qt

I'm writing a simple camera project for Raspberry Pi, via cross compiler visual studio.

**step 1**: I created a qt project using visual studio

**step 2**: coding for project

When coding for project, I declared

```
QCamera camera;
camera = new QCamera(cameraInfo);
```

When I built the project, I got this error:

> Error VGDB1000 undefined reference to `QCamera::QCamera(QCameraInfo
>   const&, QObject*)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `QT += multimedia` to your *.pro file and header `#include <QCamera>`.

Also you got the error in your code.
It should be:

```
QCamera camera(cameraInfo);
```

or

```
QCamera* camera = new QCamera(camerInfo);
```

Comment: I added QT  += multimedia into` *.pro file but when I built project:

Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia camera_raspberry